# does getIdentifier method pick the correct drawable resource?

Tags: android, android-drawable

I've different sizes of images available under drawable, drawable-hdpi, drawable-xhdpi, drawable-xxhdpi etc.. and I'm using below snippet to retrieve the images' resource id in my android app.

```
 int resid = res.getIdentifier("com.mypackage:drawable/" + selectedItem.getImageName(), null, null);
   imageFilePath = "com.mypackage:drawable/" + selectedItem.getImageName();
```

does this pick the ID of the appropriate resource based on the screen size of the device that runs the application ? (eg:- pick the drawable resource when running in an android phone and pick the drawable-xxhdpi  when running in an android tab)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, if the respective resource files (in my case images) are in the respective folders (drawable, drawable-hdpi, drawable-xhdpi, drawable-xxhdpi etc) getIdentifier method picks the respective image depending on the device that is running the app.